# image rendering in pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I need the same image to be rendered in different places.So i created a variable and used it.But the image doesn't render.What might be the problem?
I tried the below code in http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

```
var sampleData= {image: 'sampleImage.jpg',fit: [10, 10]} 
var dd = {  
    content: [{ 
          table: {
            body: [
                ['Col 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'],
                [sampleData,sampleData, 'OK?']
    ]}
}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to benefit from declaring the image once, and have it rendered multiple times in your pdf, you need to declare it at the images section of the document definition:

```
var sampleData = {image: 'sampleImage', fit: [10, 10]} 
var dd = {  
  content: [{ 
    table: {
      body: [
        ['Col 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'],
        [sampleData, sampleData, 'OK?']
      ]
    }
  }],
  images: {
    sampleImage: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...content...'
  }
}
```

And the [docs](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#images) also say that an image address in the form 'sampleImage.jpg' will only work if your code is running under NodeJS or if you are using the virtual file system provided by pdfmake correctly.